# Retrieve Odata Query in MS Crm.How to check odata is fetching how many records

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

```
Hi i'm using odata to retrieve records in MS CRM.i want to write business logic if it does not return any record.How to check that Odata Query is returning 0 records

var odata="$select=*&$filter=Name eq 'Demo'";
SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("account", retrieveContactsCallBack, errorCallBack, contactsRetrieveComplete);}
```

// retrieveContactsCallBack-It is a Success Call Back Function.
   // errorCallBack-It is a error call back function.
   // contactsRetrieveComplete-It is a on complete function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalAccountCount = 0;
var odata="$select=*&$filter=Name eq 'Demo'";
SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("account", retrieveContactsCallBack, errorCallBack, contactsRetrieveComplete);
}

function retrieveAccountsCallBack(retrievedAccounts) {
 totalAccountCount = totalAccountCount + retrievedAccounts.length;
alert(totalAccountCount);
}
```

[Retrieve multiple records using the OData endpoint with JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985387.aspx)

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot....accepting parameter for Success Call Back Function will be array or what

Comment: @Akash Glad it helped it will be an array,